# tufte-latex and subcaption

Tags: subcaption, tufte

I try to use `tufte-latex` with `subcaptions`, which seems generally problematic. A workaround mentioned of compatibility mode for the `caption` package however, works only partially:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, twoside, symmetric, justified, nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% doing this at least the labels are there, but
%   - the caption is bigger
%   - referencing the labels doesn't work
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

% instead, only to compile without errors
%\newcommand{\subcaption}[1]{}%

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Just a single image}
\label{fig:singleimage}
\end{figure}

% for comparison of font size
\lipsum[1]\footnote[][-20pt]{Note that the figure caption is larger than this
text when \textsf{captionsetup: compatibility=false}}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
    \adjustbox{minipage=1.5em,raise=-\height}{\subcaption{}\label{fig:smalla}}%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    }
    \adjustbox{minipage=1.5em,raise=-\height}{\subcaption{}\label{fig:smallb}}%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    }
    \caption{Two images ---- fig.~\ref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
      fig.~\ref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".
    }
\label{fig:twoimages}
\end{figure}
Outside referencing isn't different:
In fig.~\ref{fig:twoimages}:
Two images --- fig.~\ref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
fig.~\ref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".

\end{document}
```

Output of the above snippet

[image: partially working]

Comment out the first part and comment in the second - just to compile without errors. Now the captions have the correct size.

[image: without subcaption at all]

Comment: This is weird!  Somehow only the caption label is doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of compatibility problems, I replaced `\subcaption` with my own version.  This one does not have to be inside a minipage.  OTOH, these subcaptions cannot show up in the `\listoffigures` (normally they don't anyway).

I also replaced `\label` with `\normallabel` for the subcaptions, but continue to use `\label` for the figure caption.  I have no idea what tufte-book is doing to `\label` or why.

Lastly, I replaced `\ref` with `\hypergetref` in the caption.  The caption is written into the aux and lof files and `\ref` doesn't handle expansion well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, twoside, symmetric, justified, nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% doing this at least the labels are there, but
%   - the caption is bigger
%   - referencing the labels doesn't work

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{subfigure}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
\newcounter{subtable}[table]
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\alph{subtable}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subcaption}{\edef\sub@captype{sub\@captype}%
  \refstepcounter{\sub@captype}%
  (\csname the\sub@captype\endcsname)~}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\let\normallabel=\label}% must be after hyperef

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Just a single image}
\label{fig:singleimage}
\end{figure}

% for comparison of font size
\lipsum[1]\footnote[][-20pt]{Note that the figure caption is larger than this
text when \textsf{captionsetup: compatibility=false}}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
    \raisebox{-\height}{\subcaption{}\normallabel{fig:smalla}}%
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    }
    \raisebox{-\height}{\subcaption{}\normallabel{fig:smallb}}%
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    }
    \caption{Two images ---- fig.~\hypergetref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
      fig.~\hypergetref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".
    }
\label{fig:twoimages}
\end{figure}
Outside referencing isn't different:
In fig.~\ref{fig:twoimages}:
Two images --- fig.~\ref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
fig.~\ref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".

\end{document}
```

Comment: This makes a good start, thank you! I need to reset the counter in every figure `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}`. Also I changed `\thefigure`: `\renewcommand{\thissubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}`, change csname accordingly and add `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1\relax \thissubfigure}`  to get references as "1a". I didn't get `\autoref` to work properly up to now.

Comment: I forgot to add the automatic reset.  And the \thesubfigure macros were made to be modified.

Comment: Ah, nice. Also with `\def\subfigureautorefname{fig.}` autoref does fine. Thanks again, this is much better than my `subfigure` ansatz (I'd upvote, but can only accept (karma))

Answer (score 4):

The package `caption`, together with `subcaption`, is not compatible with `tufte-book`.

You can use `subfig`, though.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, twoside, symmetric, justified, nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Just a single image}
\label{fig:singleimage}
\end{figure}

% for comparison of font size
\lipsum*[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\captionsetup{captionskip=0pt,farskip=0pt,nearskip=0pt}

\vspace*{-\abovecaptionskip}

\subfloat[\label{fig:smalla}]{\qquad}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-a}\hfil
\subfloat[\label{fig:smallb}]{\qquad}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-b}

\caption{Two images ---- fig.~\protect\subref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
      fig.~\protect\subref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".}
\label{fig:twoimages}

\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}
\end{figure}

Outside referencing isn't different:
In fig.~\ref{fig:twoimages}:
Two images --- fig.~\subref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
fig.~\subref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".

\end{document}
```

Note that `\subref` should be used for referring to subfloats and that it should be prefixed by `\protect` if in a moving argument, such as in `\caption`.

[image]

Comment: This is nice too and less hacky. The only downside is, not having autoref, but I guess that'd be managable. Thank you!

Comment: May I ask why you include `\vspace*{-\abovecaptionskip}` and `\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}`?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung I don't remember. Why don't you try omitting them?

Answer (score 0):

Now this is some dirty hackery and uses the obsolete `subfigure` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, twoside, symmetric, justified, nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[FIGTOPCAP,nooneline]{subfigure}
\subfigcaptopadj = -12pt
\subfigcapmargin = -12pt

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Just a single image}
\label{fig:singleimage}
\end{figure}

% for comparison of font size
\lipsum[1]\footnote[][-20pt]{Note that the figure caption is larger than this
text when \textsf{captionsetup: compatibility=false}}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \vspace{-12pt}
  \centering
  \subfigure[]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \label{fig:smalla}
    }
  \qquad
  \subfigure[]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \label{fig:smallb}
    }
  \caption{Two images --- fig.~\ref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
    fig.~\ref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".
    }
\label{fig:twoimages}
\end{figure}
Outside referencing isn't different:
In fig.~\ref{fig:twoimages}:
Two images --- fig.~\ref{fig:smalla} shows an "A",
fig.~\ref{fig:smallb} shows a "B".

\end{document}
```

Renders as:
[image: dirty hackery with subfigure]

I'm open to any better solutions, especially since referencing the whole figure does not work any longer and enumeration seems broken.

Edit: yes, A /= B ...

Comment: Is the obsolete package `subfigure` really necessary?

Comment: To my understanding the superceeding `subfig` internally uses `subcaption` and thus ought to have the same issues. At a first try I couldn't reference the subfigures at all.

Comment: No, `subfig` does not use `subcaption` internally. (In fact `subcaption` was developed after `subfig` was dropped by its author.)