# Forcing single large figure and caption to be on a page in sequence

Tags: floats, page-breaking, tufte

I'm using tufte-book and have several large (full-page-size) figures which I want to place one per page.  Alas, whenever I adjust the `[width=...]` to fill the text column with the figure the compiler forces that page to be set at the end of the document (chapter).  I want that page to remain in its proper sequence in the text.  (Even at full text width, the figures' heights are not so large as to bleed to a second page.)

I have tried surrounding the figure (page) with all combinations of `\newpage` and `\pagebreak`, before and after, changed float percentages and such with combinations of:

```
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1}  
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{1}   
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0}
```

Put the page in a `\minipage` environment, placed the figure on a float page `[p]`, tried `figure*`, and so forth.

Nothing seems to work:  My full-page image (and caption) gets forced to the end of the document.

How to I typeset it in its proper sequence within the body of the chapter?

Comment: Have you tried the `figure*` environment? Have you tried `\FloatBarrier`? Have you read pages 23ff of [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf)? I don't use `tufte-latex` myself and without an MWE I can only guess (your problem may be entirely unrelated to the document class), but that's where I'd start. If this does not help, please provide an MWE for us to test.

Comment: @schtandard:  `figure*` doesn't work either.  (I should have said I had tried that.... I will update my question.)

Comment: @schtandard:  Yes...  I've read pp. 23ff of the *Manual*.  One uses the `figure*` environment for full page-*width* figures (as I've done throughout my book)... but not for full *page* figures.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1}` makes it almost impossible to have float pages, is that the intention?

Comment: neither `\newpage` or `\pagebreak` will flush a float at that point, you seem to be looking for `\clearpage` but with no example provided it is very hard to give definite help.

Comment: certainly `[p]` will force the figure to the end of the document (or the next `\clearpage`) with those float parameter settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example document showing that full-page figures can exist within the chapter. Note that since the figure is a float, text is moved around to fill the page before and after the full-page figure so there aren't unsightly gaps.

If you really want the full-page figure placed on the following page, uncomment the `\clearpage` command after the figure. This finishes the current page (regardless of how full it may be) and will place the figure on the following page.

If there are other figures interfering, then judicious use of the `\FloatBarrier` command may be needed. It will cause any unplaced figures to be placed immediately.

I would recommend not using `\clearpage` or `\FloatBarrier` until you've completely finished writing and editing your document (or at least the current chapter). If you decide to add, edit, or remove material from your document, it will cause LaTeX to rethink its placement of the floats which may then by stymied by your orders.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1-4]

\textcolor{red}{\bfseries This text precedes the figure.}

\begin{figure*}[p]
  % example-image-a is from the mwe package
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is the caption for my full-page
    figure amidst the text of my document.}
\end{figure*}

% Use \clearpage to finish the current page
% (regardless of how full it is) so that text
% following the figure doesn't appear before
% the figure is placed. This will also allow
% LaTeX to place the full-page figure.
%\clearpage

\textcolor{red}{\bfseries This text follows the figure.}

\lipsum[10-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It only works when I use the `\clearpage` command, but that is fine!  (accept)

Answer (score 0):

A MWE would be helpful.

With the `hvfloat` package (Her­bert Voß) and `\newpage` we can achieve an initial solution approach to your problem (see [page 44](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hvfloat/doc/hvfloat.pdf) and thus example [`fullpage1s2c.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hvfloat.zip) of the package). But there are some [compatibility problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356674/tufte-latex-and-subcaption) between the document class `tufte-book` and the `subcaption` together with the `caption` package. However, by adding `\captionsetup{compatibility=false}` compiles without errors.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\begin{document}
   \title{Example for fullpage floats}
   \author{Herbert Voß}
   \frontmatter
   \maketitle
   \mainmatter
   \chapter{The fullpage optional arguments}
   \newthought{blindtext} \blindtext
   \begin{figure*}[p]
      \vspace*{\the\dimexpr-1in-\voffset+\topskip-\headheight+0\baselineskip}%
      \if@twoside
      \leavevmode\checkoddpage
      \ifoddpage
      \hspace*{\the\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\parindent-1in}%
      \else
      \hspace*{\the\dimexpr-\evensidemargin-\parindent-1in}%
      \fi
      \else
      \hspace*{\the\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\parindent-1in}%
      \fi
      \put(0,0){\usebox\hvObjectBox}%
      \AtBeginShipoutNext{\thispagestyle{empty}}%\textbf{}
      \includegraphics*[FULLPAGE]{tiger}
   \end{figure*}
   \newpage
   \newthought{blindtext} \blindtext
   \newthought{blindtext} \blindtext
   \verb|\includegraphics[FullPage]{tiger}|
   \begin{figure*}[p]
      \includegraphics*[FullPage]{tiger}
   \end{figure*}
   \newpage
   \section{One}
   \newthought{blindtext} \blindtext
   \section{Two}
   \newthought{blindtext} \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]