# figure* environment has wrong placing in sidenotes package

Tags: positioning, margins, sidenotes

I'm trying to use the `figure*` environment with the `sidenotes` package so that my tikzpictures can extend across both margins, because I've seen that in many math textbooks, and it is useful for organization. However, when I use the `figure*` environment the tikzpictures only extend past the right margin, not the left, and thus are not given enough spacing, and are not centered with respect to the entire page width including the margins. I graphed a rough tikzpicture for this example. (By the way, according to the sidenotes [documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes/sidenotes.pdf) (3 pages, 6 pages implementation), the sidenotes package requires the packages `caption`,`marginnote`,`l3keys2e`,`xparse`, and `\usepackage[strict]{changepage}`, which is why my preamble has all those packages.) The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=2in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption,xparse,marginnote,l3keys2e}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\title{figure* test}
\author{Devano Bethel}
\date{August 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,4} \draw (-5pt,\y) -- (5pt,\y);
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- (1,4) -- (2,1) -- (3,4) -- (4,1) -- (5,2);
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,4} \draw (-5pt,\y) -- (5pt,\y);
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- (1,4) -- (2,1) -- (3,4) -- (4,1) -- (5,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

gives this output:
[image: document]

I have tried using `\centering`, and `\begin{center} \end{center}` so that the picture gets centered, but nothing gets the picture to move past the left margin, it only starts at the left margin and moves past the right margin. I even tried shifting the tikzpicture to the left using `\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=-5cm]`, which still didn't do anything. `\reversemarginpar` doesn't do anything either. Also, normally I set my documents like this using the geometry package:

```
\usepackage[right=0.5in,marginparwidth=6cm,textwidth=12.7cm]{geometry}
\reversemarginpar
```

so that I can put figures in the left margin using the `sidenotes` package's `marginfigure` environment, which works, but since I set the right margin to be smaller, it worsens the problem I have with the `figure*` environment. Any help is appreciated.

As a "sidenote" (pun intended) I'm not sure weather the best way to have multiple graphs side-by-side is to use `\begin{scope}[xshift=cm]`, as I did in my code above, or to use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace={cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks for your help, and let me know if you need any further information to answer my question.

Comment: Extending figures into the margin is specialty of tuftebook class.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356674/tufte-latex-and-subcaption for example.

Comment: But, there are plenty of other examples on this site where that is not the case. For example, here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633593/caption-of-sidenote-packages-figure-widefigure-has-wrong-margin-or-width-in

Comment: The class does look interesting though, thank you for the info.

Comment: Technically, the marginpar area is only on one side.  You can also use `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` to center a wide image relative to the text area.

Comment: Thanks! I also realized that once I looked at the Tufte-book class—the figures don't extend past the left margin, is just looks better because the left margin is very small, so the picture is more centered. The only weird thing is that the command \reversemarginpar switches the side marginnotes (`\marginfigure` command) and figures are placed on, but it doesn't switch the side that the figure starts at with the figure* environment. If I can't figure out how to do that, then I'll probably just revert to using a large right margin instead of a large left margin so that everything will work out.

Answer (score 1):

- In one column article use of `figure*` has not sense. It is intendent for spanning figure across two columns.
- In preamble you load `changepage` package. Why you not use its macro `adjustwidth`?
- People usually allow that images (or table) extend only out of outside text border and left margin free for pages bindings
- However using `adjustwidth` you can extend figure (or table) out of both text borders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{caption,xparse,marginnote,l3keys2e}

\title{figure* test}
\author{Devano Bethel}
\date{August 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
%    \rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- + (0.48\linewidth,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,4} 
    \draw (-5pt,\y) -- (5pt,\y);
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- (1,4) -- (2,1) -- (3,4) -- (4,1) -- (5,2);

\begin{scope}[xshift=0.52\linewidth]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- + (0.48\linewidth,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw (-5pt,\y) -- (5pt,\y);
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- (1,4) -- (2,1) -- (3,4) -- (4,1) -- (5,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Use of \texttt{changepage}, figure extend only to outside margin.}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
    
        \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{-\marginparwidth}{-\marginparwidth}
%    \rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw (-5pt,\y) -- (5pt,\y);
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- (1,4) -- (2,1) -- (3,4) -- (4,1) -- (5,2);

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4);
\foreach \y in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw (-5pt,\y) -- (5pt,\y);
\draw[blue] (0,2) -- (1,4) -- (2,1) -- (3,4) -- (4,1) -- (5,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Use of \texttt{changepage}, figure extend out of both margins.}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what are page bindings? Also, I only used changepage because, as I said in the post, the sidenotes package documentation said the \usepackage[strict]{changepage} was a requirement. However, I've seen some examples without all the required packages listed, so I'm not sure if I actually have to include them all in my preamble. Do you know if that's true?

Comment: @DevanoBethel, space for binding is reserved for gluing (or otherwise) keep) together. If you not need `changepage` for locally making  text width  wider (or narrower) , than your images are far to wide and you get a warnings `Overfull \hbox (101.97623pt too wide) in paragraph at lines ....`. For `sidenotes` you not need to load the `changepage` package. Sorry, what actually is your problem? It is not clear now :-(